# Concatenating tripple quoted strings horizontally

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Straight into the `code`:

```py
a= """
   ###
   # #
   ###
   # #
   # #
   """

a= """
   ###
   # #
   ###
   # #
   ###
   """
```

Namely `a = A` with hashtags and `b = B` with hashtags.

How can I concatenate them to have:

```py
expected result:
   ### ###
   # # # #
   ### ###
   # # # #
   # # ###
```

When I do `a+b`, the result is: they are under each other, I tried with

```py
print(f"{a}{b}") - result is still the same (under each other)

print("{a}{b}".format(a=a,b=b)) - result is the same (under each other)
```

Any idea on how to put those next to each other ?

UPDATE!

I created a package:
[image: Link to PyPi package]
https://pypi.org/project/comment-creator/

Comment: you have to split text to lines and use `for`-loop to concatenate lines separatelly - and later concatenate back lines to one text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split text to lines and use `for`-loop to concatenate lines separatelly - and later concatenate back lines to one text.

**EDIT:** as Matthias said in comment you can also print it directly in loop and then you don't have to `join()` it back.

```
a= """
   ###
   # #
   ###
   # #
   # #
   """

b= """
   ###
   # #
   ###
   # #
   ###
   """

a = a.splitlines()
b = b.splitlines()

c = []
for x,y in zip(a,b):
    #c.append(x+y)
    c.append("   " + x.strip() + " " + y.strip())
    #print("   " + x.strip() + " " + y.strip())

text = '\n'.join(c)

print(text)
```

---

**EDIT:** for more chars it would be good to keep it on list

Using `strip()` can makes problem to add empty space between words so I used `[:-3]`

```
a= """
   ###
   # #
   ###
   # #
   # #
   """

b= """
   ###
   # #
   ###
   # #
   ###
   """

SPACE = """





    """

a = a.splitlines()
b = b.splitlines()
SPACE = SPACE.splitlines()
word = [a,b,SPACE,b,a]

for lines in zip(*word):
    print(' '.join(x[-3:] for x in lines))
```

Result `AB BA`

```
### ###     ### ###
# # # #     # # # #
### ###     ### ###
# # # #     # # # #
# # ###     ### # #
```

Comment: Alternative: `print` without gathering the data in a list: `for line_a, line_b in zip(a.splitlines(), b.splitlines()):     print(f'{line_a.strip()} {line_b.strip()}')`

Comment: brilliant. Thanks a lot. will accept in a sec when I am allowed.

Comment: I added example with more chars in line.